# What rspec tests should be used?

Tags: ruby, testing, methods, rspec, tdd

I am learning rspec and am curious about some examples of tests I can run for the following coding problem where I need to create an object that takes a long string and returns the frequency of each word in it, similar to the code below:

```
WordTracker.new('Toy boat toy boat toy boat').frequency

{
  "toy" => 3,
  "boat" => 3
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
describe WordTracker do

  context '#frequency' do
    {'toy boat toy boat toy boat'=>{'toy'=>3, 'boat'=>3},
     'toy boat boat toy boat fred'=>{'toy'=>2, 'boat'=>3, 'fred'=>1},
     'etc'=>{'etc'=>1}
    }.each do |given, expected|
      specify "for '#{given}' expect '#{expected}'" do
        expect(WordTracker.new(given).frequency).to eq(expected)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a data-driven method would be best for something like this.  How about?

```
describe WordTracker do

  describe '#frequency' do

    [
      {
        in: '',
        out: {}
      },
      {
        in: 'toy boat toy boat toy boat',
        out: { 'toy' => 3, 'boat' => 3 }
      },
      {
        in: 'toy',
        out: { 'toy' => 1 }
      }
    ].each do |example|
      it "should convert #{example[:in]} to #{example[:out]}" do
        expect(WordTracker.new(example[:in]).frequency).to eql(example[:out])
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Just threw this together, may not execute cleanly, but hey, you're learning, good exercise.